# Nginx Proxy - How to check images are cached?

Tags: nginx

On nginx server, i have config

```
location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|3gp|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|flv|mp3|mid|js|css|html|htm|wml)$ {
   root /var/www/cache;
   expires 365d;
}
```

i check the folder /var/www/cache but do not find any images.

```
Nginx server: 1 cpu 1gb ram

Apache server : 2 cpu 2gb ram
```

Comment: root /var/www/cache; is called the document root of your domain where static files are stored. This is not related to caching. Why do you want to Cache images which are already static?.

Comment: I do not understand at this point. My site is hosted on apache server and this server is separated with nginx server. I want to use nginx to serve static files. So i think i need to cache images on nginx server, then nginx server can serve them faster, right ?

Comment: Nginx serves static assets directly from the document root. So you must specify the correct document root location where all css,images are there. So your config in above will change to root /var/www/html;

Comment: Ok, i have set to doucment root on apache server. I use nginx with 1 core 1gb ram and apache with 2 core 2GB Ram. why nginx can work faster when it needs to connect with apache server to serve static file.

Comment: I had left a comment here linking to other Questions on ServerFault addressing the same issue, but I realized one of those questions was yours from a few days ago. Have you gone through the other existing questions?